# query to select customers who bought only in a certain year

Tags: mysql, select

Hi i have a table that looks like this

[image: table]

I need to select customers who only bought in the year of 2015 meaning that i dont need customers who bought in 2015 and also 2016 only the ones who bought only on 2015 . but sadly i cant figure this out 
any help would be Aprichiated

is it possible to write it like

```
     select customerid
      from x 
      where year(date)="2015" and year(date)!=2016
```

thank you :)

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by finding the customers with a purchase in 2016 first, then taking all the customers with a purchase in 2015 except those also listed in the 2016 group:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.customerid
FROM x AS t1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT customerid -- select the 2016 consumerid group
    FROM x
    WHERE date BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-12-31'
) AS t2
ON t1.customerid = t2.customerid
WHERE date BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-12-31'
AND t2.customerid IS NULL -- only take rows without consumerid match in 2016
```

I also added `DISTINCT` to avoid getting duplicates (if a client purchased several times in 2015)

As mentionned by @Strawberry, `year(date)` cannot use indexes, so I changed it to `BETWEEN`